# Pandas: Group people into households to generate descriptives

Tags: python, pandas

My problem can be simplified as having two dataframes;

Dataframe 1 contains people and the household that they live in:

```
Person ID | Household ID
1           1
2           2
3           2
4           3
5           1
```

Dataframe 2 contains individual characteristics of people:

```
Person ID | Age  |  Workstatus  | Education
1           20      Working      High
2           29      Working      Medium
3           31     Unemployed    Low
4           45     Unemployed    Medium
5           30      Working      Medium
```

The goal is to group people belonging to the same Household ID together, in order to generate descriptives about the family, e.g. 'average age of persons in household",  "average education level", etc.

I tried:

```
df1.groupby['Household ID']
```

but I'm not sure where to go from there, how to do it the 'pandas' way. The 'real' dataset is very large so working with lists takes too long.

The ideal output would be:

```
Household ID | Avg Age of persons | Education
1               25                   High/med
2               25.7                 High/High
3               28                   Low/Low
```

Comment: whats your ideal output?

Comment: I added the ideal output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `.map` to get the household IDs and `groupby` with Named Aggregations

```
df3 = (
    df2.assign(houseID=df2["Person ID"].map(df1.set_index("Person ID")["Household ID"]))
    .groupby("houseID")
    .agg(avgAgeOfPerson=("Age", "mean"), Education=("Education", "/".join))
)
```

---

```
print(df3)



         avgAgeOfPerson    Education
houseID                             
1                    25  High/Medium
2                    30   Medium/Low
3                    45       Medium
```

Comment: this does exactly what I want. Thanks, I will look into the .map function.

Comment: Think of it a as a `left` join with a little flexibility if you come from SQL then its similar to a `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both the datasets and then groupby on household id:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[2,2],[3,2],[4,3],[5,1]],columns = ['Person ID', 'Household ID']) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,20,'Working', 'High'],[2,29,'Working','Medium'],[3,31,'Unemployed','Low'],[4,45,'Unemployed','Medium'],[5,30,'Working','Medium']],columns = ['Person ID','Age','Workstatus','Education']) 

merged = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = 'Person ID', how = 'left')

merged.groupby('Household ID').agg({'Age':'mean', 'Education':list}) 

Result:

              Age       Education
Household ID                     
1              25  [High, Medium]
2              30   [Medium, Low]
3              45        [Medium]
```